# Sound output very low but jumps up when opening audio controls

Tags: 20.04, sound, pulseaudio

In all apps that use audio the sound level is very low.

As soon as I open the audio controls such as PulseAudio volume control, the sound seems to jump up by about 50%.   If I use zoom, just by having that volume control app open, my workmates can hear me clearly.  With it closed, the volume drops below 50% after 2 seconds.

How do I fix this?

I have tried setting:

`flat-volumes = no`

And restarting, but that made no difference.

Comment: Is the allow volume over 100% option enabled?

Comment: Also, have you tried installing `alsa-tools` and using the `alsamixer` command? Note, if you have more than one card, you may need to press F3 and then select the correct card.

Comment: And just to verify, you're using the PulseAudio volume control provided by the `pavucontrol` package, correct? (and not the default PulseAudio settings window that you get after clicking on the volume icon on your desktop)

Comment: volume over 100% can be enabled.  Enabling it makes it VERY loud but I still experience the issue of the sound dropping low after closing the pulseaudio volume control.

Comment: Installing alsamixer seems to have helped.  So far so good.  The volume was down around 30% on the headphone output device.

Comment: Cool. I will add this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes using `alsamixer` helps to give a more static control over the input and output volume.

First, install the `alsa-tools` package:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install alsa-tools
```

Then, run the following command:

```
alsamixer
```

You may need to press <kbd>F6</kbd> to select your sound card if you have multiple audio devices.

Press <kbd>F5</kbd> to show all parameters.

Use the left and right arrow keys to select a different item, up and down arrows to increase or decrease the volume. When a parameter is selected, press <kbd>M</kbd> to toggle mute on or off (this will be shown below the volume bar as `MM` when muted or `00` when mute is off).

Also, it's usually suggested to disable or toggle the **automute** item OFF (I believe up or down arrow or <kbd>SPACE_BAR</kbd> will toggle this item).